# How to set input only allow letter and number in html

Tags: html, input

How do i set  to allow letter and number only.(not allow space and special character) in html>

```
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" required/><br />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a "pattern" attribute:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+" oninput="this.value = this.value.toUpperCase()" required/><br />
```